Why is Valid annotation not set for Path Parameter variables by OpenApi Generator?
When I run openApiGenerate, I do not see "@Valid" tag in the generated interface method.
Following is my yaml file:


openapi: "3.0.0"
info:
  version: 1.0.0
  title: Swagger Petstore
  license:
    name: MIT
servers:
  - url: http://petstore.swagger.io/v1
paths:
  /pets:
    get:
      summary: List all pets
      operationId: listPets
      tags:
        - pets
      parameters:
        - name: limit
          in: path
          description: How many items to return at one time (max 100)
          required: true
          schema:
            type: integer
            maximum: 100
            format: int32
      responses:
        '200':
          description: A paged array of pets
          headers:
            x-next:
              description: A link to the next page of responses
              schema:
                type: string
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: "#/components/schemas/Pets"
        default:
          description: unexpected error
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: "#/components/schemas/Error"



Generated interface method which is missing "@Valid":


    default ResponseEntity<List<Pet>> listPets(
        @Max(100) @Parameter(name = "limit", description = "How many items to return at one time (max 100)", required = true, in = ParameterIn.PATH) @PathVariable("limit") Integer limit
    ) {



The annotation is generated correctly when I change the parameter Query instead of Path. Can someone advice why Valid does not get generated for Path parameter, even though it works for Query parameter?
